# Pagination on reactionGroups in the GitHub GraphQL API

Tags: github, graphql, github-api

I’m trying to extract the username of all the users that have reacted to an issue (and how they reacted) with the GitHub GraphQL API. I’ve only been able to extract a maximum of 11 users per reaction group per query, and I haven’t found a way to successfully paginate the queries - the same users are returned each time.

Here’s an example of my query using [an issue with many reactions](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/3184):

```
{
  repository(owner: "mapbox", name: "mapbox-gl-js") {
    issue(number: 3184) {
      reactionGroups {
        content
        reactors(first: 30) {
          totalCount
          pageInfo {
            hasNextPage
            endCursor
          }
          edges {
            node {
              ... on User {
                login
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For `THUMBS_UP` reactions this correctly returns `totalCount: 77`. However, there are only 11 usernames returned (not the 30 requested). The value of `hasNextPage` in `pageInfo` is false, and using the returned cursor value or modifying the reactors query to `last:30` instead of `first:30` has no impact on which 11 users are returned.

Is there a way I can modify my query to get this working (I’m new to GraphQL) or is this a current limitation of the API? Thanks!

(I've also asked this on the GitHub community forums, but no reply yet - [see here](https://github.community/t/pagination-not-working-on-reactiongroups-reactors/192255))